# SQL Traer top 1 o max

Tags: sql-server, sql

Tengo la siguente consulta:

```
select  top 1 fact.vend, fact.cliente, sum((detalle.precio-art.costo)*cant) as total
from afacturas as fact
inner join afacart as detalle on fact.comprob = detalle.comprob
inner join aarticulos as art on detalle.cordart = art.codigo
group by fact.cliente,fact.vend  
order by vend
```

La que devuelve el total acumulado por cada cliente que tiene cada vendedor:

```
1   1   1800
1   12  4800
2   5   2300
2   11  42500
3   2   4600
3   4   1700000
4   16  160000
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que me devuelva solo el top 1 de cada cliente que tiene la mayor cantidad de plata por vendedor.

Por ejemplo:

```
1   12  4800
2   11  42500
3   4   1700000
4   16  160000
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu DBMS (SQL Server, Oracle...)? Si agrupas sólo por el cliente debería darte lo que esperas. Es decir, cambiar esto: `group by fact.cliente,fact.vend` por esto: **`group by fact.cliente`**

Comment: Uso sql server 2015.

Comment: ¿No funciona agrupando sólo por el cliente?

Comment: si le saco el grup by de vendedor y solo dejo el de cliente me tira el error de que falta otro GROUP BY **Column 'afacturas.vend' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**

Comment: ¿Y necesitas la columna `vend` en tus resultados?

Comment: si, porque es el cliente con mas plata de cada vendedor. ClienteVip por asi decirlo.

Comment: De paso, no existe SQL Server 2015. Hay 2012, 2014, 2016, ... pero no 2015.

Comment: @sstan me confundi con SQL Manager 2015, tenes razon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente, no es posible que tu primera consulta con el `TOP 1` devuelva los resultados que dices. Debes estar refieriéndote a la misma consulta, pero sin la claúsula `TOP 1`.

En cuanto a la solución a tu problema, puedes agregar a tu `SELECT` una llamada a la función ventana `ROW_NUMBER` para asignarle un rango a los registros por vendedor (`partition by fact.vend`) según la mayor cantidad de plata (`order by sum((detalle.precio-art.costo)*cant) desc`). Luego, es cuestión de solo devolver los registros que tengan un rango de `1` (`where rnk = 1`):

```
;with cte as (
  select fact.vend,
         fact.cliente,
         sum((detalle.precio-art.costo)*cant) as total,
         row_number() over (
           partition by fact.vend
               order by sum((detalle.precio-art.costo)*cant) desc) as rnk
    from afacturas as fact
   inner join afacart as detalle on fact.comprob = detalle.comprob
   inner join aarticulos as art on detalle.cordart = art.codigo
   group by fact.cliente,fact.vend
)
select vend, cliente, total
  from cte
 where rnk = 1
 order by vend
```